# Excel: Import Data from Picture Command is Missing?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

[This MS web page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-data-from-picture-3c1bb58d-2c59-4bc0-b04a-a671a6868fd7) says Excel 365 has an "Import Data from Picture" command:

> Excel for Microsoft 365 for Mac Excel for iPhone More...
>
> Want to turn images that have table data into data that you can edit
> in Excel? With the new Data from Picture feature, it's a snap.
>
> ...Click Insert > Data From Picture > Picture From File.

But there appears to be no such command available in my current Office 365 subscription version of Excel :

[image]

Is this command available in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke to Microsoft Tech support and they confirmed the missing command is a bug in Excel that needs to be fixed!

Comment: Hm, I still do not see this.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to these pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is different. That will just import the picture into the sheet **as a picture.** The `Import Data from Picture` function is supposed to "turn images that have table data into data that you can edit in Excel", per the Microsoft link included in the original post.